# jquery each json function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to use `each()` on a JSON array but my alert function isn't running.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgLf6p8g/)

**JS**

```
var calduration = function(){   
    $.each(videoinfo, function(i, obj) {
        alert(obj.startdatetime);
    });
};
var videoinfo = [{"startdatetime":"2014-12-21 00:23:14","totalsecondrun":"2019402310","videolist":
[{"videoid":"uoSDF234","second":"192312"},{"videoid":"0apq3ss","second":"180"}]}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `videoinfo` above from `each` function, and `calduration` is function so you will need to self call using `()` or call function, see below sample code

```
var videoinfo = [{"startdatetime":"2014-12-21 00:23:14","totalsecondrun":"2019402310","videolist":
[{"videoid":"uoSDF234","second":"192312"},{"videoid":"0apq3ss","second":"180"}]}];
var calduration = function(){   
        $.each(videoinfo, function(i, obj) {
            alert(obj.startdatetime);
        });
}();
```

**OR**

```
calduration();
```

**OR**

```
calduration.call();
```

**UPDATE**

```
$.each(videoinfo[0].videolist, function(i, obj) {
                alert(obj.startdatetime);
            });
```

Or if `videoinfo` have multiple objects then you can iterate two times using `each()` function

```js
  var videoinfo = [{
    "startdatetime": "2014-12-21 00:23:14",
    "totalsecondrun": "2019402310",
    "videolist": [{
      "videoid": "uoSDF234",
      "second": "192312"
    }, {
      "videoid": "0apq3ss",
      "second": "180"
    }]
  }];
  $.each(videoinfo, function(i, obj) {
    $.each(obj.videolist, function(j, o) {
      alert(o.videoid);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did u know how to each the `videolist` json ?

Comment: you can use `videoinfo[0].videolist` key in `each()` or if above object multiple then two iterate by `each()` function.. see updated answer

Comment: `videolist` another object that is inside parent `videoinfo[1], [2]....n` object.

Comment: @ImHappy see demo link in answer

Comment: hi, cannot help me one more thing ? how to select the `videoid` is `uoSDF234` and get it second

Comment: `videoid` key is in object array, that comes in second `each()` function

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `calduration()`.

```
var videoinfo = [{"startdatetime":"2014-12-21 00:23:14","totalsecondrun":"2019402310","videolist": [{"videoid":"uoSDF234","second":"192312"},{"videoid":"0apq3ss","second":"180"}]}];

var calduration = function(){   
    $.each(videoinfo, function(i, obj) {
        alert(obj.startdatetime);
    });
};

calduration();
```

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/yvq7kn5v/).

To loop through the `videolist` array. You could add an inner loop:

```
$.each(videoinfo, function(i, obj) {
    $.each(obj.videolist, function(i, obj2) {
        alert(obj2.videoid);
    });
});
```

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y2a3nm4d/).

Comment: thanks noted that =) that json cannot put on bottom ?

Comment: oh one more thing! how to each `videolist` item ? like `videoid` and `second`

Comment: You can define `videoinfo` after you've declared `calduration()` but you must do it before calling `calduration()`. Personally it makes more sense to me to define it before the function it is used in.

Comment: i see, how bout another json `videolist` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var videoinfo = [{"startdatetime":"2014-12-21 00:23:14","totalsecondrun":"2019402310","videolist":
[{"videoid":"uoSDF234","second":"192312"},{"videoid":"0apq3ss","second":"180"}]}];

$(document).ready(function() {
        $.each(videoinfo, function(i, obj) {
            alert(obj.startdatetime);
        });
    });
```